# Is there a way to get GCP service cost by access email ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm looking to get help on the GCP billing. I know we can get cost info based on the service and project, however, is it possible to get info based on the access email ID? because I'm planning to give access to my colleagues and I want to know how much each one their access cost and against which service.

Something like: Date, Email ID, Service, Cost

[image]

With respect to another project, how should we know which access cost us so much?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are running ~30 sandbox projects internally, each allocated to a specific person that can test and run his/her stuff on GCP.

I strongly suggest you create isolated workspaces (projects) for your colleagues so they don't accidentally delete/update services of other people. You will get a separate billing report for each project as well.

I am also setting up a [billing alert](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) for all my colleagues so they get an early notification if they left something running on their testbench.

Comment: Hi @petomalina, thanks for your reply and suggestion, however, one of our project generated bill of $10k which at least 10 of our employees were accessing, now, we don't know how to check who used what because many employees were accessing and using same services (check second screenshot for your reference).

Comment: @user3816325 oh I got it, so you already have a bill. You can definitely look into the audit logs in Stackdriver to get emails of people that created the services/data fusion/cloud spanner instances etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways I think you could do that kind of cost segregation, I will number them in order of complexity.

1.- [Cloud Export Billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery), For this one the best practice is to segregate your resources and users by "Labels", as administrator, you may ask the users to use them and assign them to any resource they create, e.g. If they create a new VM instance, then you will be able to filter by field the exported table and create the reports as you want.(Also your GCP billing dashboard will show these "labels" segregations)

2.- Use [Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis) to curl directly the information you need to get from it,you can manage to use in the request the information you need like SKU, User, Date and description.

3.- [Usage Reports](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started?hl=en_US). This solution is more GSuite scope,and I can't vouch that will work as the documentation say but you can take a look to it, there is an option to get "Usage reports", this usage reports can be made from GSuite to any resource below, GCP included if you already have an organization.